# is there any way we can access the variable that is assigned to await function call out the function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

getdata function

```
async function getdata() {
  try {
    const configData = await redis.getAsync("configdata");
    const strifieddata = JSON.parse(configData);
    return [strifieddata];
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error in data", err);
  }
}
```

function for getting the configdata

```
const {getbyconfigid,getdata}=require('./middlewareNew/configHelpers')
const getconfigdata=async()=>{
  storeddata=await getdata()
}
getconfigdata();
console.log(storeddata)
```

without await i can able to access the value like if i pass the inside function variable i can access that but i couldn't able to get the value of the function with async

Comment: No, when you `console.log(storedddata)`, `getConfigData` hasn't finished running yet, and has not set the value of `storeddata`. No time travel allowed. If you want to access that value, you need to `await` the result of `getconfigdata()` or use the promise directly using `.then` and/or `.catch`.

Comment: but if i make use of ,then function and set the variable name i can't able to access them outside the function,is there any way to actieve that,i am try to but the value inside variable and access the entire file

Comment: No because that would require time travel. Check this out https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/ . Async functions are red, synchronous functions are blue.

Comment: There is no other way i can access the value of the function is returning

Comment: Imagine you sent someone to the store for milk, and then walked into the kitchen and tried to take the milk out of the fridge. This wouldn't work because you haven't `await`ed the return of the shopper with the milk. This is what's happening here. If you don't `await` getconfigdata, you can't have the config data because it's just literally not here yet. This isn't the language enforcing arbitrary rules, this is an order-of-operations issue.

Comment: You can't magically make an async function synchronous.